# Finding data relations of json paths in python

Tags: python, array, set

I am kind of new to python, so I am pretty sure there are way better elegant ways to do this.
I have made a function that is able to compare two list of possible json object paths, and detect what elements do not belong to the other list.

**In the docstring you will find** a better description with **examples**.

I will also provide the **test class with a lot of examples**

It will also be appreciated any help on better docstring, since I am not really sure how to describe correctly what this method exactly does

**Note**: The code works on both Python 3 and 2.

my_utils.py

```
"""
Utils
"""


def list_diff(list1, list2):
    """Returns a new list with the items in list1 that do not belong to list2"""
    return list(set(list1) - set(list2))


def get_unknown_data_relations(expected_data_relations_paths, real_data_relations_paths):
    """
    Obtain all those fields which are expected to be data_relations but they are not.

    This function does not check afterwards the real_data_relations_paths, if a expected_data_relations_paths
    is expected to have  any field, it will assume it's correct .
    (['pet.field'],['pet']) is correct, but, (['pet2.field'],['pet']) it is not

    :param expected_data_relations_paths: list of field paths expected to be a data_relations
    :param real_data_relations_paths: list of field paths with real data_relations

    .. Examples:
        expected_data_relations_paths = ['pet'], real_data_relations_paths = ['pet']
        Output = []
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        expected_data_relations_paths = ['name'], real_data_relations_paths = ['pet']
        Output = [name]
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        expected_data_relations_paths = ['name.field'], real_data_relations_paths = ['pet']
        Output = [name.field]
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        expected_data_relations_paths = ['pet'], real_data_relations_paths = ['pet', 'pet2']
        Output = []
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        expected_data_relations_paths = ['pet.field'], real_data_relations_paths = ['pet']
        Output = []
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    """
    filtered = []
    for expected in expected_data_relations_paths:
        temporal_expected = expected
        for data_relation in real_data_relations_paths:
            if related(expected, data_relation):
                temporal_expected = data_relation
                break
        filtered.append(temporal_expected)
    return list_diff(filtered, real_data_relations_paths)


def related(path1, path2):
    """Returns True if path1 is related to path2, False otherwise"""
    return list_diff(path2.split('.'), path1.split('.')) == []
```

Testing file:

```
"""
You can auto-discover and run all tests with this command:

    $ pytest -c env_vars [-s]

Documentation:

* https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/
* https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html
"""
from my_utils import get_unknown_data_relations


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_perfect_match():
    """Tests the most simple case with perfect match"""
    assert len(get_unknown_data_relations(['pet'], ['pet'])) == 0


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_missing_element():
    """Tests a missing element"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['unknown_field'], ['pet']) == ['unknown_field']


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_single_expected_multiple_data_relations():
    """Tests single expected belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['pet'], ['pet', 'pet2']) == []


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_multiple_expected_multiple_data_relations_exact_dimension():
    """Tests multiple expected belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['pet', 'pet2'], ['pet', 'pet2']) == []


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_multiple_expected_and_unexpected_multiple_data_relations_exact_dimension():
    """Tests multiple with an  unexpected do not belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['pet', 'pet4'], ['pet', 'pet2']) == ['pet4']


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_multiple_expected_multiple_data_relations_different_dimension():
    """Tests multiple expected belong to multiple data_relations with different dimension"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['pet', 'pet3'], ['pet', 'pet2', 'pet3']) == []



def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_empty_expected_empty_data_relations():
    """Tests empty expected belong to empty data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations([], []) == []


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_empty_expected_multiple_data_relations():
    """Tests empty expected belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations([], ['pet', 'pet2', 'pet3']) == []


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_expected_embedded_single_data_relation():
    """Tests single expected embedded belong to single data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['pet.name'], ['pet']) == []


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_expected_embedded_multiple_data_relation():
    """Tests single expected embedded belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['pet.name'], ['pet', 'pet2']) == []


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_multiple_expected_embedded_multiple_data_relation():
    """Tests multiple expected embedded belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['pet.name', 'pet2.name'], ['pet', 'pet2']) == []


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_unkown_expected_embedded_single_data_relation():
    """Tests single unknown expected embedded do not belong to single data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(['unknown_relation.unknown_field'], ['pet']) == ['unknown_relation.unknown_field']


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_unkown_expected_embedded_multiple_data_relation():
    """Tests single unknown expected embedded do not belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(
        ['unknown_relation.unknown_field'],
        ['pet', 'pet2']
    ) == ['unknown_relation.unknown_field']


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_some_unkown_expected_embedded_single_data_relation():
    """Tests some unknown expected embedded do not belong to single data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(
        ['unknown_relation.unknown_field', 'pet.field'],
        ['pet']
    ) == ['unknown_relation.unknown_field']


def test_unit_get_unknown_data_relations_some_unkown_expected_embedded_multiple_data_relation():
    """Tests some unknown expected embedded do not belong to multiple data_relations"""
    assert get_unknown_data_relations(
        ['unknown_relation.unknown_field', 'pet.field'],
        ['pet', 'pet2']
    ) == ['unknown_relation.unknown_field']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this is a little bit unclear

```
def list_diff(list1, list2):
    """Returns a new list with the items in list1 that do not belong to list2"""
    return list(set(list1) - set(list2))
```

since you don't just return a new list with the items in `list1` that are not in `list2`, but you also remove duplicates from `list1` (which maybe is what you want to do?), and you change the order of the list. If you wanted to "return a new list with the items in list1 that are not in list2" (quoting because I'm not sure what you mean by "do not belong to"), you could also write `return [digit for digit in list1 if digit not in list2]`.

And I think I also find the docstring for

```
def related(path1, path2):
    """Returns True if path1 is related to path2, False otherwise"""
    return list_diff(path2.split('.'), path1.split('.')) == []
```

a little bit confusing. I would also like it if you type hinted, or if you expanded on your docstring to include argument and return description; you write a little with reST-style in the function above so why not also here? Speaking of this function, by the way, I like that you're comparing against an empty list. It may bring a tiny overhead in creating the list, but it helps the readability a lot.

I think the "main" function (`get_unknown_data_relations`) also could benefit from a little bit of work on the docstring. It's descriptive, but 6 examples (if you count also the in-line one) seems a bit exaggerated. It could maybe also be turned into something a bit more pythonic, but it's good enough to not struggle with trying to turn it into a list comprehension.

---

I like that you've written tests. I don't (have to) write docstrings for my tests, so I would skip that since the names tend to describe the tests well enough, but maybe you have a different workflow. I would recommend looking into [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) if you haven't. You could also have a look at mutation testing, but maybe you already have and maybe all of your tests are already sufficiently safe.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!! I appreciate them a lot!! :) Didn't you find anyythin wrong in the anidated loops? It is where I struggled more, needed to write break... I don't find it like a clean style code, specially in python where you can do pretty things as the one you described for my list_diff (Which I'm not used to since I come from java, js, and c)

Comment: I've updated the answer now @Mayday.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that doesn't produce the same results @ades, since the "else path" gets executed extra times (that's why I had a break). But it helped me a lot to learn other stuff, like arguments types declarations, and the view of your more "pythonically" way to do things! :) :)

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Yeah it actually complicates things a little. I think you could use [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), but it's honestly fine to just leave it as it is; it's readable and it works.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! Edit please the last non-working part, so I will accept the answer :)

Comment: Done, and you're very welcome.